# Not working Bootstrap site on nginx + php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx

There are next folders and files in my site-directory:

```
 |-css/
 |-js/
 |-fonts/
 |-index.php
```

I see my index.php without styles

nginx conf file:

```
server { 
    listen  80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name xx.xx.xxx.xxx;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000; 
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

How I need to write my static locations in nginx?

Comment: You're going to have to clarify your problem a little better.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
   listen 80;

   root /var/www/phpMyAdmin;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;

   server_name phpmyadmin.dev;

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri /index.php =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
   }

}
```

Comment: I use nginx in docker-compose so we have different root path

Comment: No problem change root path,i think to  need add "fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;" this

Answer (score 0):

If your static directories is in the same directory as index.php you can add them like

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/css/style.css">`

or

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="your_domain/css/style.css">`

If you want a special directory for these files you can add a location to your nginx configuration. And you can add a custom cache policy for them.

```
server { 
    listen  80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name xx.xx.xxx.xxx;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    // You can add a custom location for a directory
    location /css {
         root different_root_for_css;
    }

    // You can add a custom location for file types
    location ~* \.(js|jsx|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css)$ {
        // root path for these files
        root different_root_for_these_files;
        //Custom cache policy
        expires 365d;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000; 
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

You can check [nginx resources](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content) for more information.

Another method; some websites use subdomains for static files. This way if you plan to use a cdn provider, you can change your subdomain dns and it will work same.